# Applying insert or update on aggregated column in ADF Dataflow

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I have dataflow that is doing some joins and a count on columns which then sinks into Azure SQL table.
Azure SQL table structure has a GUID as ID column.

What I want is that when the values in the count column change, for it to update in the Azure SQL table. Rather than an insert.

I use this code in SQL for it to work, but I want to implement this in ADF Dataflow. I am using Alter Row expression true() for upserts. Doesn't seem to be working when it comes to counts. Not sure where I am wrong.
Please ask for clarification if needed.

Below is the SQL code that works and I want to implement that in ADF.

```
MERGE [Target] AS [T]
USING [#Temp] AS [S]
ON [T].[Filter] = [S].[Filter]
   AND ISNULL([T].[OrganisationGroup], '') = ISNULL([S].[OrganisationGroup], '')
   AND ISNULL([T].[ItemCatalog], '') = ISNULL([S].[FinancialReference], '')
   AND ISNULL([T].[CIType], '') = ISNULL([S].[CIType], '')
   AND ISNULL([T].[ConfigurationItemTypeName], '') = ISNULL([S].[ConfigurationItemTypeName], '')
   AND ISNULL([T].[Status], '') = ISNULL([S].[Status], '')
  AND ISNULL([T].[Further_Detail], '') = ISNULL([S].[Further_Detail], '')
   AND ISNULL([T].[PartitionKey], '') = ISNULL([S].[PartitionKey], '')
WHEN MATCHED AND [T].[CICount] <> [S].[CICount] THEN
    UPDATE SET [T].[CICount] = [S].[CICount]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT
```

Comment: Can someone answer please

Answer (score 0):

I have repro’d in my lab with some sample data, please find the below steps.

Existing data in the SQL table (table tb2):

[image]

**ADF data flow:**

1. Connect the source to the **input** dataset. Here I have new records compared to existing SQL data, so the count will be updated, and new records will be inserted if not matched.

[image]

2. Adding **aggregate** to get the count of the input records.

[image]

[image]

Aggregate data preview:

[image]

3. Adding **Alter row** transformation to perform upsert.

**Upsert condition:**

`and(and(isNull(Name)== false(),isNull(Department)== false()),isNull(Status)== false())`

[image]

**Note**: Here, include all columns except count as we are performing upsert based on Count column.

Alter row data preview:

[image]

4. Connect **Sink** to SQL table. In settings, enable **Allow upsert** and include a list of key columns.

[image]

Sink preview:

[image]

5. After execution, Count in the **sink table** is updated for existing records when the count is not matched and new records are inserted.

[image]

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer. I will give it a go. So if a new row is added, it will be inserted, correct? but if a count for existing rows changes that will change. Usually the count in my case is dependant on status. If my status goes from Active to decommissioned I want that to show as well.

Comment: Are you there..? @NiharikaMoola-MT

Comment: Hi, yes with this approach new records get added, and existing ones will be updated if any changes. Have you tried with your data?

Comment: Hi, I did. I can let you know by tomorrow when the new data comes in. Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain to me what the query is doing? What does false mean in this instance etc